# Lua: looking for an open source graphical interpreter / console / interactive shell

Tags: shell, open-source, lua, interpreter

I'm looking for an open-source Lua interpreter (sometimes called a lua console or a lua shell) with the following features:
- Ability to write lua commands and see results
- Simple graphic UI 
- Auto-completion of global objects, class methods
- Ability to watch the value of global variables, packages, etc.
- If it comes integrated with script file editor or lua debugger it's even better...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Lua is a proper name. Not an acronym. It is "Lua", not LUA.

Comment: What you're asking for is an IDE, not an interpreter.

Comment: I do not think one exists. Maybe you should write one ;) Sounds like it might be a fun project

Comment: Nicol, first- thanks for the correction on the name. Second, I would settle for interpreter, and found that most IDEs don't have one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua plugin for IntelliJ that I developed contains 2 interpreter UI's in addition to a host of other features.

Here is a screencast of one of the interpreter UI's: http://www.screencast.com/t/0f262SeCKmqT

The other is in the image below.

Lua for IntelliJ IDEA.   https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home

Features:

- Introduce Variable Refactoring (**Experimental**)
- Debugger (**Experimental**)
- Modules support (**Experimental**)
- LuaDoc Highlighting and Folding
- Lua SDK REPL Console
- Basic Completions
- Quick Documentation with Multiple documentation providers
- Resolving Globals in project and libraries
- Custom API Support including custom function signatures
- Function Information via Quickhelp
- Lua Standard Library Information via Quickhelp (ctrl-Q)
- Hilighting of Upvalues and Fields
- Goto Symbol
- Safe Delete
- Rename Identifier
- JavaHelp For Lua 5.1
- Execution in the Kahlua interpreter
- Go to definition
- find usages
- Code formatting
- Keyword completion
- 1 quickfix
- 6 code intentions
- 11 code inspections
- Highlighting global vs local variables
- Script execution and run configurations
- Kahlua interpreter window for interactive script execution (repl)
- Comes with an embedded Lua compiler written in Java (Kahlua)
- Structure view
- Syntax checking
- Syntax highlighting - including proper handling of extended syntax comments and quotes
- Customizable highlighting colors
- Code folding for code blocks and comments
- Brace Matching for do blocks, long strings and comments, and (, { , [
- Minor feature: comment in/out.

[image]

Comment: That looks awesome. The only drawback it has is that integrate into IntelliJ: while I'm sure IntelliJ rock (I really like other JetBrains products like resharper and team-city) I already use and maintain two seperate IDEs: eclipse and VS..

Comment: Having said that, I will try it. :) Should I use any particular stable version or just the tip?

Comment: It is available from within the IDE itself. Settings|Plugins

Comment: The list of features is largely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

[ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) provides a Lua console (both local to execute commands in the IDE and remote to execute them in the context of the client application). You can also modify variables in the application and get values [pretty printed](http://studio.zerobrane.com/screenshots.html) (including complex hierarchical data). The IDE does come with the debugger, Stack and Watch views and auto-completion.

The [code for the console](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/src/editor/shellbox.lua) is available on GitHub, but for remote execution it mostly relies on capabilities provided by the debugger (MobDebug). If you want to integrate something like this in your application, then the source file I referenced may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

The usual contenders are:

- [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/)
- [Decoda](http://unknownworlds.com/blog/lua-ide-decoda-open-source/) (now Open Source)

You can also go with IDE plugins:

- [for IntelliJ](https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home)
- [Koneki LDT for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a platform so I'll make some suggestions that are focused on Windows and leave other platforms and/or platform portability for other answers.

First, start with the [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) bundled installation. That gives you the Lua interpreter along with an assortment of useful and interesting modules that are all built consistently and known to work on Windows. It also gives you the [SciTE editor](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) which has code coloring for Lua, some context help for library functions, and an integrated debugger that can debug Lua programs out of the box.

There has been work on an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) [plugin for Lua](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/) to add syntax coloring. Debugging support is certainly possible, but I don't know its current status.

There are Lua coloring plugins for both [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [vim](http://www.vim.org/). Recent releases of vim are scriptable in Lua as well (possibly after configuring a plugin).

Comment: I've looked at SciTE and Eclipse, none of those contains an interpreter. Just syntax-highlighting and running full Lua files.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this improvement to the standard lua shell: https://github.com/ilua/ilua